# Should I [not] put type sigs in titles throughout the Haskell tag? q -> IO [MSOUser] -> a

Tags: discussion, title

For those of you familiar with Haskell you know type signatures are extraordinarily small and concise, and I find often times when hoogle's not doing the job a question on SO will find the already written function for me.

Though I wrote a dupe function request for a function which was already dupe requested, and this is probably common.

So what does anyone think about going through the [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell) tag and forall questions looking for a function that does X, tacking the type sig of that function into the question title; this may make it simpler for people to find other SO questions for their function resulting in less dupes.

For those of you unfamiliar, a Haskell type signature is easily small enough to fit into the vast majority of question titles e.g. `Show a => a -> Int -> [Char]` (that's right, `(flip replicate).head.show` for the win). Hoogle is a type-signature search engine for Haskell.

Should I [not] do this? What does that even mean when I put brackets around it? Thoughts?

Comment: At a glance, it seems likely that the syntax could be confused with the system-generated information such as `[duplicate]` and `[on hold]`.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins anyone who knows Haskell and is therefore looking for these questions would absolutely not confuse it. And any of these questions would be of no relevance or use to someone who doesn't know Haskell anyway

Comment: That's exactly my point: Haskell aficionados will understand, and everyone else will be confused. Since Haskell users do not comprise the entire SO userbase, and since the questions are visible to _anyone_ who happens to encounter them, the potential for confusion cannot be ignored.

Comment: It hay be fine for Hoogle, but it's not appropriate here IMO, for the same reason @GeorgeCummins mentions. "Haskell afficionados" are a relatively small percentage of the users here, and it would be extremely annoying for others (like me) who are not among that user base.

Comment: Hmmm. Having a look through, many questions don't have a single function to give the type of, and those that do aren't always great quality, so might not benefit from being bumped. (Sometimes the type signature is the problem.) Having said all that, it would be easier to spot some things.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins No, quite a number of Haskell questions have type sigs with lists in, and it's really, really, really not hard to tell the difference between :: [[a]] -> [a] and [on hold]

Comment: @KenWhite, GeorgeCummins That's really not the issue. Recent example question title: __Haskell printing [[[Char]]] to IO__. Who on earth is confused by the presence of square brackets in a question title and stresses over whether it means [on hold]? It means [on hold] if it says [on hold]. It's just a complete non issue. Should we avoid using array syntax like myarray[i] in a question title in case someone who doesn't use that syntax is confused? Did you think the [not] or the q -> IO [MSOuser] -> a in _this_ question title was autogenerated close text? NO! It's a _nonsense_ point.

Comment: The issue is whether it makes a better title, and whether it's worth editing old questions to make them more findable. Certainly in Haskell, more so than in most languages. the type signature is crucial data that tells you a lot about the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Testing out SO's search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[haskell]+%22Int+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[[a]]%22) with a type sig `[haskell] "Int -> [a] -> [[a]]"` yields good results, containing a range of functions you might be interested in.

- (Type signatures in question titles are **fine**, and I don't think anyone has been confused by their presence.)
- Unlike hoogle, **SO's search doesn't understand the type signature** - swapping the order means you get [different results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[haskell]+%22[a]+-%3E+Int+-%3E+[[a]]%22), whereas hoogle would check all orderings of input arguments, and even some variants on the theme of your signature.
- **You have to put the type signature in `"` quotes `"`**, otherwise it turns lists into tags and doesn't care what order or where it finds things, so searching for (contrived) `a -> a -> [[String]]` without quotes would match anything that has a [string] *tag*, and contained `->` and the word a.
- Searching for the type signature already searches the body of the post. This means **you don't need to have it in the title for it to turn up in search**.

So, I think

1. It already works if the type signature is part of the text in the question or an answer.
2. Editing that into the title doesn't bring benefits unless there's no copy of it in the text.
3. It's not such a reliable search that it's worth the effort.
4. The benefit isn't strong enough to churn through lots of the tag's questions.

Comment: Actually my purpose was specifically to benefit people with the title list that shows up in dupe Q list when you're writing a Q, but yeah I suppose your right if normal search works well enough, hell hoogle should maybe execute the same query against SO properly quoted, that would be nice for when hoogle results are particularly unhelpful but this isn't metahoogle :)